# Swift - Return a string in a POST request with Vapor 3

Tags: swift, post, vapor

I have a problem where the user needs to post a new order via POST request. The server needs to return an ID of an order, so the front-end code can check if the order was accepted. How can I do so?

This is my code:

```
router.post("postNewOrder") { req -> Future<HTTPStatus> in
    print(req)
    return try req.content.decode(OrderRequest.self).map(to: HTTPStatus.self) { orderRequest in
        print("latitude: \(orderRequest.latitude), longitude:\(orderRequest.longitude)")

        let newOrder = Order()
        newOrder.latitude = orderRequest.latitude
        newOrder.longitude = orderRequest.longitude

        orders.append(newOrder)

        return "1234abcd"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: btw it'd be better to switch to Vapor 4 since Vapor 3 is deprecated already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all change return type to `Future<String>`

Then if you don't use any databases but just some `orders` array

```swift
router.post("postNewOrder") { req -> Future<String> in
    return try req.content.decode(OrderRequest.self).map { orderRequest in
        let newOrder = Order()
        newOrder.latitude = orderRequest.latitude
        newOrder.longitude = orderRequest.longitude
        orders.append(newOrder)
        return "\(newOrder.id)"
        // if id is String then simply
        // return newOrder.id
        // if id is UUID then this way
        // return newOrder.id.uuidString
    }
}
```

Or if you use `Fluent` then you have to save a new order into database

```swift
router.post("postNewOrder") { req -> Future<String> in
    return try req.content.decode(OrderRequest.self).flatMap { orderRequest in
        let newOrder = Order()
        newOrder.latitude = orderRequest.latitude
        newOrder.longitude = orderRequest.longitude
        return newOrder.create(on: req).map { newOrder in
            return "\(newOrder.requireID())"
            // if id is String then simply
            // return newOrder.id
            // if id is UUID then this way
            // return newOrder.requireID().uuidString
        }
    }
}
```

You also can change return type to `Int` or `UUID` depending on which type you use for `\Order.id`

Also you can return some struct like this

```swift
struct NewOrderResponse: Content {
    let id: UUID // or String, Int, etc.
}
```